# MS Excel: How to insert words in cells using Find and Replace

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have several cells like this:

```
----------------------------------
|Test point 1 using a microscope.|
----------------------------------
|Test point 2 using a microscope.|
----------------------------------
|Test point 3 using a microscope.|
----------------------------------
```

and I want to insert some text between every "point x" and "using" so that the cells become:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Test point 1 for impurities using a microscope.|
-------------------------------------------------  
|Test point 2 for impurities using a microscope.|
-------------------------------------------------
|Test point 3 for impurities using a microscope.|
-------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to use regular expressions to replace the text in all cells at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a long way around but, you could try splitting the text into multiple columns by using 'Text to Columns' DATA >> Data Tools >> Text to Columns

And then use the CONCATENATE function to add the new text in as required.

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively just Find/Replace "using" with "for impurities using".  No need for regex, unless it's more complicated than your examples.

Highlight your section you need to replace (if necessary), and run the find/replace with "Replace All".

Comment: It's more complicated - not all cells have "for impurities" after "point x" although I could do it in several runs depending on what's instead of "for impurities".